# horizontal scroll in ngx-perfect-scrollbar

Tags: angular, angular5, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

1. i am using **ngx-perfect-scrollbar** for scroll, vertical scroll was running fine, but horizontal scroll not working

   ```
   <perfect-scrollbar style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 200px;">
       <ul class="tab-menu">
           <li>
               <a>All</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a>Company</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a>People</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a>Announcement</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a>Event</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </perfect-scrollbar>
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried with this

```
<perfect-scrollbar style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 200px;" [config]="{useBothWheelAxes: true, suppressScrollX: false, suppressScrollY: false}">
    <ul class="tab-menu">
        <li>
            <a>All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Company</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>People</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Announcement</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a>Event</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `useBothWheelAxes` option to `True` as mention in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar).

This value is `False` as default

Comment: yes, i use **[config]="{useBothWheelAxes: true}"** but nothing happen

Comment: after looking into the docs I actually i dont think anymore useBothWheelAxes= true might help. Can you add more code?